# How to get the values from Listbox on binding in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Following code will display a form of data. Here Textbox and checkbox will display for it's question datatype. If Question required Yes/No Answer, checkbox will be displayed or it needs Text Answer, Textbox value will be displayed. I have atleast 15 questions How am I get this answers from "Button_Click" event.

```
<ListBox Name="formDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="0">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Name="Text">
         <TextBlock Name="Txt_Question"
            Text="{Binding Question, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
         <TextBox Name="TxTAnswer"
            Text="{Binding Stringval, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}"></TextBox>
         <CheckBox Name="BoolVal"
            IsChecked="{Binding BoolVal, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Visibility="{Binding DataType, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource YesNoConverter}}"></CheckBox>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<Button  Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Content="Submit"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing in full MVVM approach, then `Command` property seems more appropriate. As also suggested in the other answer, you can bind the command to a handler in your viewmodel, where I assume `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` data resides, then the rest should be easy because the handler and data are in the same class.

Anyway, given the XAML you have at the moment and the event handler, another possible way is by accessing the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` and cast it to the actual type :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //assuming that you're using List of Question class model.
    var questions = (List<Question>)formDetails.ItemsSource;
    //for this purpose ObservableCollection is preferable than List btw
    .....
}
```

Comment: Unable Cast directly as list.If I Do like above I got Error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`'

Comment: I did the following it works. Thanks
 List<Question> GetList = new List<Question>();
foreach (Question item in formDetails.ItemsSource)
{GetList.Add(item);}

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using data binding to populate the list and its items, consider using commands instead of the click event handler:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Content="Submit"></Button>
```

This way, you can handle the button-pressed logic in your Viewmodel instead of the page's code-behind where it should be easy to iterate through the list and retrieve all the answers...